# What is the default clock known as?

Tags: stock-android

What is the default clock (that appears at the top right corner, next to battery indicator) called?

Comment: In what context?  Are you trying to hide it?  Is it set incorrectly and you're trying to set it to the right time?  Do you just want to know what it's called?

Comment: I just want to know its name, am not trying to hide/set. This is because, by knowing the name I can search in forums wherein I can customize this clock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clock don't have a specific name, although if I do need to mention them specifically, since the top bar is usually called the notification bar or status bar, I'd probably call them notification bar clock or status bar clock.

Comment: Thanks Lie, this name should help me in getting the stuff I have been looking for customizing the clock.